# Update a field in all One2many lines when a line is added or removed

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to calculate the cost of shipping of an item in a box that can have several items. The box has a fixed shipping cost and the cost per item is calculated by dividing the shipping cost by the number of items.

In the UI I want the cost shown on each line to be updated when an item is added or removed from shipping (a line added or removed).

I expect the cost field of the line to be updated when a new line is added before saving the form. However, the value is not updated and the `onchange` call returns an empty value (this is what I see in fiddler).

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 844836927, "result": {"value": {}}}
```

This snippet is part of a larger class that contains the relevant code:

```py
class Shipping(models.Model):    
    _name = 'shipping.shipping'
    shipping_cost = fields.Float(string='Shipping cost')
    shipping_line_ids = fields.One2many('shipping.line', 'shipping_id', string='Shipping items')

    @api.onchange('shipping_line_ids')
    def onchange_shipping_line_ids(self):    
        number_of_items = len(self.shipping_line_ids)
        if number_of_items == 0:        
            return    
        line_cost = self.shipping_cost / number_of_items    
        for line in self.shipping_line_ids:        
            line.cost = line_cost

class ShippingLine(models.Model):    
    _name = 'shipping.line'    
    shipping_id = fields.Many2one('shipping.shipping', string='Shipping') 
    cost = fields.Float(string='Cost')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: IIRC the framework was limited by not allowing onchanges on x2many fields. Here is the [issue](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/2693) where one of the framework guys answered why.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will find another way to implement this functionality. Maybe a widget that requests the item cost from the server.